# I want to extract the element webpage title on vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to extract from this website using VBA the element Title in format text on this code

```
<div class="train-logo
      train-logo-monochrome
      train-logo--trenitalia-monochrome
      train-logo--frecciarossa-monochrome" title="Trenitalia">
    </div>
```

VBA:

```
For Each treno In IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("div")
    If treno.getattribute("title") Then
        Cells(rownumber2, "u").Value = treno.innertext
```

Comment: How are you trying to do that, and what happens when you run your code?

Comment: I've develop a macro on excel that go internet exploerer and get element as price for example. In this case i want to get in format text the title="trenitalia" from this url https://www.trainline.eu/search/milano/firenze/2017-03-21-14:00

Comment: If you have code, it's best to include it in your question, otherwise it's likely to get closed.

Comment: i tryed with this vba code  For Each treno In IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("div")
If treno.getattribute("title") Then
Cells(rownumber2, "u").Value = treno.innertext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim treno, t

For Each treno In IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("div") 
    t = treno.getattribute("title")
    If t <> "" Then Cells(rownumber2, "u").Value = t
Next treno
```

It's not clear from your question how many of these you need to read from the page: if just one you can `Exit For` after getting the value.

Comment: the macro run but  don't paste the value title on the cells once again read the web page